# What do "." and ".." mean in a file path in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, path, symlink

For example in this path:

```
../..pictures/Sergey_Brin/Sergey
```

And this path:

```
./videos/./Larry_Page
```

I know that the dots are some kind of symbolic links. But what do they mean exactly and what's the difference between the two.

Comment: These directories work the same on just about every computer.  They are not specific to android. i.e. even MS-DOS has them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`..` represents the parent directory.

`.` represents the current directory.

For example, `ls ..` will list the contents of the current parent directory and `ls .` will list all files in the current directory .

Take a [look](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Quick_Introduction_to_Unix/Special_Directories).

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths make use of two special symbols, a dot (.) and a double-dot (..), which translate into the current directory and the parent directory. Double dots are used for moving up in the hierarchy. A single dot represents the current directory itself.

source: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

The path ../.. simply means that you are referring to the directory two levels up from the current one.  ".." is the directory right above the current directory and ../.. is the one two levels above.
"." means current directory